# How to use .htaccess to log ips?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've got a directory I'm protecting with .htaccess and .htpassword but I think some people have shared the access username and password, which is against my terms. The other possibility is that they are using bruteforce. How can I use `.htaccess` to log the IP addresses of the people who try to access my protected directory, for both accurate and failed logins?

Comment: I have the .htaccess referring people who fail to an error document...someone suggested I need to change the coding of the php document but the .htaccess file itself is fine. Is this true?

Comment: This question is very broad and hence not a good fit for Stack Overflow - plus .htaccess isn't likely to help you with logging. A better approach would be Googling `<name of the server you use> how to log ips`. For Apache, the access log will typically be in a file named `access.log`

Answer (score 0):

That is beyond the scope of `.htaccess`. You will need to modify your webservers configuration if it doesn't log failed logins already. (Hint: Those can be identified by the 401 response code)